# How to enforce only Https only request to identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 configured and deployed on Azure App Service, I have used the custom SSL certificate to sign tokens.   Everything is working fine, however I want to enforce identity server to receive request from https clients only and throw error otherwise.

I read this part of the documentation on identityserver4(http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/crypto.html?highlight=HTTPS) where they say:
"**We don’t enforce the use of HTTPS, but for production it is mandatory for every interaction with IdentityServer.**"

Just was wondering is it possible to enforce only https client request.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That'd typically something you'd configure at web server/traffic manager level rather then at application level (although you can ofcourse have application logic to enforce it too).

This should be of use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl

Also check out the HSTS header: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet

And also consider the use of a robust Content Security Policy that blocks or upgrades insecure resource requests. e.g. `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed-content;` Check out https://report-uri.com/home/generate and https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the HSTS header and HTTPS redirection with the following calls in the Configure method in the Startup class.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
 //...
 app.UseHsts();
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 //...
}
```

For all the configuration options and best practices refer to this link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl